# Does "every" block the use of "both"?

Tags: meaning, quantifiers

Consider this sentence

1. Both of my friends are blond.

What it implies is that obviously I have only two friends and they are both blond.
Now, if I say

2. Every friend of mine is blond.

Can I still have only two friends? That is to say does the use of "every" block the use of "both"?

Would #2 be felicitous if it's taken for granted I have exactly two friends?

Comment: You can have no friends and "Every friend of mine is blond" would be true. You can have a thousand friends, all of which happen to be blond, and "Every friend of mine is blond" would still be true. In no case does "every" imply "two" unless you already mentioned you have two friends.

Comment: @ChongDog Any universal statement is true for an empty set. If you have no friends, then "Every friend of mine is blond" is true, as well as "Every friend of mine is bald" and "Every friend of mine is a tyrannosaurus rex". For  more, check out this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669002/if-everyone-in-front-of-you-is-bald-then-youre-bald-does-this-logically-mea) on Mathematics SE. Of course, I'm aware no one would interpret such thing, but no one would interpret the thousand friends thing either. Sound people would just think you have *some* friends and that all are blond.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the term "blocking" nor the term "felicitous" seems applicable here; but it's true that we don't generally use *every* when *both* would work, so "every X" creates an *[implicature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature)* (more specifically a *[scalar implicature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_implicature)*, I think) that there are at least three X-es. But, importantly, it does not *entail* this. Something like this is perfectly valid:

> A: Did you check every room?
>   B: Yes — every single one of the two rooms. ;-)

Comment: I think want you mean is a presupposition, (scalar) implicatures and entailments are something different (for more info check the Maximize presupposition principle (Heim 1991)). And yes, both "blocking" and "felicitous" are applicable here. Nevertheless, my question wasn't a question about pragmatics theories, I just wanted to know if a native speaker could say "Every friend of mine is blond" given that there are only two friends. Apparently they can.

Comment: @IrinaStan: I think they only can if there's something special to license it. In ordinary conversation, if someone knows that there are only two Xes, and yet says "every X" instead of "both Xes", then they're probably trying to deceive in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If you say 'Every friend of mine is blond', we cannot infer how many friends you have, except that it is one or more.